# Who is right about maximum CPU clock on AMD Ryzen 5 7640U?

Tags: cpu, turbo-boost

Running Ubuntu 23.10 on AMD Ryzen 5 7640U I get:

```
paul@box4x4:~$ lscpu -ae
CPU NODE SOCKET CORE L1d:L1i:L2:L3 ONLINE    MAXMHZ   MINMHZ       MHZ
  0    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes 4971.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  1    0      0    1 1:1:1:0          yes 5121.0000 400.0000 1576.8660
  2    0      0    2 2:2:2:0          yes 5425.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  3    0      0    3 3:3:3:0          yes 5275.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  4    0      0    4 4:4:4:0          yes 5579.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  5    0      0    5 5:5:5:0          yes 5579.0000 400.0000  400.0000
...
```

which indicates maximum clock frequency of 5.579 GHz for cores 4 and 5.

Looking at AMD specs at https://www.amd.com/en/product/13196, I see:

[image]

which indicates "maximum frequency achievable by a single core" of 4.9 GHz.

Which value is accurate?

---

Running `7z` benchmark on allegedly faster cores and monitoring `/proc/cpuinfo`, I don't observe frequency higher than 4.940GHz. Why is `lscpu` showing higher numbers?

Comment: IIRC `lscpu` just reports what the kernel reports in sysfs. Maybe check there as well so you can narrow down what's to blame.

Comment: @DanielB Do you mean */sys/fs*? I know Linux too little to follow your suggestion. I looked at */sys/devices/cpu*, but all files there are very short and I don't see frequency data.

Comment: _sysfs_ is mounted at `/sys`. In it, you can find information about Linux and the hardware it runs on. I’m not very familiar with it, but CPU frequency info should be available at `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/`.

Comment: @DanielB The values in these files and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*` are the same as listed by `lscpu`.

Comment: That means the key to this mystery is to be found somewhere in the Linux kernel. Unfortunately, I cannot help with that. Maybe a more Linux-specialized community could provide more information.

Comment: @DanielB Is there another community more appropriate to ask this question?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I don't know any, sorry.